# SPAN mirroring in cisco switch - Invalid input error

Tags: cisco, mirror

[image]

I'm trying to enable span mirroring in cisco switch, but the switch doesn't seem to have the "monitor" option. Could someone tell me how to make this work?

Comment: Is this packet tracer? it doesn't have all feature of a real IOS device. If not we need your switch model and software version to help you.

Comment: Could you please attach the show version of the Switch?<br/> On Cisco Packet Tracer 7 the monitor session configuration works for the 2960, 2950 and 3560 Switch
<br/> [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Wzg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Wzg.png)

Comment: In addition to @JFL's remarks, *please* copy/paste output instead and format it using `{ }` instead of posting images.

Comment: Yes, I'm using cisco packet tracer 6.3 @JFL

Comment: Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASE-M), Version 12.2(25)FX, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1) - @cost

Switch>enable
Switch#config
Configuring from terminal, memory, or network [terminal]? 
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Switch(config)#no monitor session 1
                   ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Packet Tracer has some built-in functionality to allow you to view the packets on the wire and won't support the monitor commands.

However, if you weren't on tracer, the setup is straightforward. E.g.

```
monitor session 1
monitor session 1 source int gi1/0/2 both (-- specifies span tx and rx
monitor sessions 1 destination int gi1/0/3
```